# Resolving asset location issue using Ruby SCSS transpiler in WebStorm

Tags: ruby, sass, phpstorm, webstorm

I have this structure of SCSS:

```
app
    styles.scss
    bower_components
        _colors.scss
        _fonts.scss
    sass
        index.scss
```

styles.scss:

```
@import "sass/index";
```

index.scss:

```
@import "bower_components/_colors";
@import "bower_components/_fonts";
```

`app` folder is set as working directory in File Watcher settings and is marked as "Resource Root" in WebStorm. However, transpiling fails with error: 
`error sass/index.scss (Line 3: File to import not found or unreadable: bower_components/_colors.)`

I've read that `@import`s evaluated in SCSS

1. relative to current file location
2. relative to root location

But in my case it is obvious that Ruby transpiler doesn't do attempt to find files relative to root location. Is it a bug? Or I am doing something wrong?

I installed SCSS through Ruby and set up File Watcher according to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html

This is my File Watcher settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get exactly the same issue when running scss.bat in command line:

```
C:\Projects\prj>cd app

C:\Projects\prj\app>C:/Ruby193/bin/scss.bat --no-cache --update sass/index.scss
error sass/index.scss (Line 1: File to import not found or unreadable: bower_components/_colors.)
```

See https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/652: current working directory being automatically placed on the Sass load path is deprecated in 3.3. You need passing the load path explicitly with `-I` option to work with folders relative to the working directory. Like:

[image]

Comment: That helped. There is also a verbose synonym to `-I`: `--load-path`.

Comment: By the way, some tips in this dialogue window would be helpful. Before reading several helps, I actually thought that Working directory setting was what sets load path...

Comment: the dialog window is the same for all file watchers (that is actually just a UI that allows setting up ANY tool as a watcher), there is no way to add specific tips there. Available options are different for different tools/versions